# .lower() Returning True when presented with 0

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to complete a task of ensuring all characters in a string meet the following conditions:

- Divisible by 4
- Contains "A1" in the string
- String only contains Uppercase and Numbers

For most strings the function works; however, I am returning a false `False` when a 0 is presented.

The problem is localized to the for loop (`for character in string:`) as shown by the output.

```
def valid_product_code(string):
if len(string) % 4 == 0:
    print("String is divisible by 4")
    if "A1" in string:
        print("A1 is contained within string")
        for character in string:
            print(character)
            if character == character.lower():
                print("Character is a Lowercase")
                return False
            elif character == ("!"or "." or "," or ":"):
                print("Character is punct")
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False
else:
    return False
```

print(valid_product_code("0O3LG6EWN7AA1NI596LCVBRZ"))

The output of the code is as follows:

```
String is divisible by 4
A1 is contained within string
0
Character is a Lowercase
False
```

Comment: "String only contains Uppercase and Numbers" You only check for uppercase, not for numbers. Why would you assume the code accepts numbers?

Comment: Your loop will return `True` as soon as a *single* character passes the tests. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I do check for uppercase you're correct; however, if a number is presented it should be handled by the "else" to return True. My question is why the character.lower() is True (hence returning False) when presented with a number.

Comment: @GlennChamberlain If your question is "Why is `'0'.lower() == '0'`?", you should [edit] the question to make this clear. The question currently has a lot of interpretations, from "why is it not working?" to "how should it be written instead?".

Comment: Test this line `if character == ("!" or "." or "," or ":"):` with various values for `character`; you will be surprised by the results. A working (!) replacement line would be `if character in ("!", ".", ",", ":"):`

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is un-pythonic. Instead of using `if character == character.lower():`, use `.islower()`.

`.islower()` returns `True` when there are no uppercase letters in the string and there is at least one lowercase letter. That's not the same thing as all characters being letters.

Comment: It's not un-Pythonic.  It's just an incorrect use of a method.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `if character.islower():` not `if character == character.lower():` because `'0'.lower()=='0'` so that if statement (`if character == character.lower():`) will always return `true` if your string contain any digit

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is `'0'.lower() == '0'`.  Instead of checking for bad characters (such as lower-case letters or punctuation), you should describe in Python what it means to be a good character.

In this case, being a good character simply means

```
'A' <= character <= 'Z' or '0' <= character <= '9'
```

Comment: There is no need to use ``ord`` and ``range``. Characters compare by their Unicode/ASCII numbers. ``'A' <=  n <= 'Z'`` checks for uppercase letters, ``'0' <= n <= '9'`` for digits.

Comment: ... then how about `character in string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits`